# convert characters in a string C

Tags: c, string

I am working on a program to change take a word or multiple words from the user(at most 100 characters). for example if the user put in dakka dakka, they would get d@kk@ d@kk@ printed out. I am doing something wrong and it only prints the first word of what I type.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
 char utext[100];
 int i, len;
 char c;

 len = strlen(utext);

 printf("type in your message to be converted: \n");
 fgets( utext, 100, stdin );

 for ( i = 0; i < len; ++i )
  {
  c = utext[i];

  if (c == 'a')
   c = '@';
 printf("%c", c);
  }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: use `strlen` only after you have read the string.

Comment: Change `fgets( utext, 100, stdin );` to `if (NULL==fgets( utext, sizeof(utext), stdin)) return -1;`

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `strlen()` on an uninitailized array.

The `strlen()` function searches for the terminating `'\0'` which is not in `utext` before you call `fgets()`.

Also, you don't want to iterate over the 100 characters, which would be done if you change `strlen()` with `sizeof()`, because that will give you the size of the array in bytes, reason for which

```
fgets(utext, sizeof(utext), stdin);
```

is ok, and not just ok, it's better because now you can change the size of the array without needing to alter this line.

For the `for` loop, I would recommend using two facts

1. `fgets()` reads the trailing `'\n'` which is inserted by the user when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed, and is almost mandatory.
2. Any valid c string, i.e. one that would return it's length when passed to `strlen()`, must have a terminating `'\0'`, so if `'\n'` is not present for some reason, then `'\0'` would be.

From the two points above, the `for` loop should look like

```
for (i = 0 ; ((utext[i] != '\n') && (utext[i] != '\0')) ; ++i)
 {
    c = utext[i];
    if (c == 'a')
        c = '@';
    printf("%c", c);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider reading in by characters, then you dont even have to store the string. A code like this would work:

```
int c;
while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    if(c == 'a')
        printf("@");
    else
        printf("%c", c);
}
```

Comment: `getchar` does not return `NULL` or a `char`. It returns an `int` the character value read, or `EOF`.

Comment: You're right, I edited the code. Although I tried it and it worked with char and NULL.

Comment: `while((c = getchar()) != NULL)` gives the compiler warning *warning C4047: '!=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'void *'*, also a `char` won't hold `EOF` without truncating it to `0xFF` making it indistinguishable from the char `0xFF`.